Ansible Switch Description Query + Append Value
Trying to write an ansible-playbook that will query a switchport description, register it as a variable and then reapply it plus add text and the date/time.
- name: Verifying Interface Description
  ios_command:
    provider:
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    commands:
      - command: "show derived-config interface GigabitEthernet{{ switch_interface }} | include description"
  register: interface_description

- debug:
    msg:
      "{{ interface_description }} Updated {{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

But the value I get when I run the playbook is:
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [NG-1-DA] => {
    "msg": "{'failed': False, u'changed': False, u'stdout_lines': [[u'description DataJack123']], u'stdout': [u'description DataJack123']} Updated 2024-04-23"
}

The text and the date/time work, but for some reason the reference to the interface description fails and I can't seem to figure out why.
I'm not sure I understand the error message associated with the interface_description variable and why the reference is failing.

There is no error in the above question. You get what you asked for: a textual description of the dict which is a result of running your task. You'll probably get a better understanding of you debug that var on its own. Since the module you use gives back a field with standard output and you seem to be interested only in that info, just use it => msg: "{{ interface_description.stdout }} Updated {{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

What I'm hoping to do is leverage the value returned by the command -
TASK [Current Interface Description] ***************
ok: [NG-1-DA] => {
"interface_description.stdout": [
"description Testingjack123"
I use a regex to remove the word "description" which works, but when it actually applies the config string to the interface, it looks like this -
TASK [Configuration] ***************************
"interface GigabitEthernet1/0/25",
" description [u' Testingjack123'] Updated 2024-04-25"
How do i only return the value of "Testingjack123"

I found there answer in this post - Ansible Print IOS output on string match
I had to use the {{ interface_description.stdout_lines | join(" ") }} to turn it back into a string, as it was previously a list value.

interface_description.stdout is already a string with all lines from interface_description.stdout concatenated.
